# Text boxes in Word 2010 do not print to actual size

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2010

In Word 2010, I'm trying to make text boxes that are an exact size when printed. However, when I print them, they come out smaller than that specified size.

For example, if I make a text box that is 4.25" x 5.88" (4-1/4" x 5-7/8"), it ends up being 4" x 5-1/2" when printed.

[image]

If I check the print settings, scaling is not enabled.

[image]

I've tried this on an HP inkjet and Konica Minolta MFC, so it's not printer or brand specific. I've also tried on different computers, which offered no change in results.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried this on more than one printer? What printer are you using? It is possible this is effected by the print drivers themselves.

Comment: I've tried this on an HP inkjet and Konica Minolta MFC, so it's not printer or brand specific. I've also tried on different computers.

Comment: Using 2010 also, I was unable to duplicate this issue. Have you installed all updates for Office?

Comment: Yes, it is up to date.

Comment: Then I would suggest creating a new document to see if you are able to print a box the way you want. If that works, the original document was corrupt. If it does not work, run a repair install on your computer and try again.

Comment: I ended up printing each page one at a time, and they came out at the correct size. Not sure why I had to do that, but ok...

Comment: This is not a Question and Answer forum, What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Comment: I did. And of course this is a Q&A forum. Search results were inconclusive. They only mentioned the scaling option, and that obviously is not the cause here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ending up being the paper size. The template was from a European website where they use A4 paper (8.27" x 11.69"), which is slightly different size than US letter size (8.5" x 11") paper.

Switching the paper size to 8.5" x 11" allowed everything to print at the correct size.